# How can I disable the parent screen when I have a modal displaying?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

When I have a modal on show, the user is still able to fill in an input on the parent page and the button also works. I need to prevent this behaviour so the user can do nothing until they  have pressed the continue button on the modal.

I've looked at other answers to this on stack overflow, but none of them seem to work.

```
 <!-- timeout warning pop-up -->
   <dialog id="popupDialog" style="display: none;" class="popup">
     <div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="govuk-modal-title" tabindex="-1">
       <h1 class="govuk-heading-l" id="govuk-modal-title">{{t('sign-out-warning:heading')}}</h1>
       <div class="govuk-modal-content" role="document">
         <p>{{t('sign-out-warning:paragraph')}}</p>
       </div>
       <button class="govuk-button" id="closePopup">
        {{ t('sign-out-warning:continue') }}
       </button>
     </div>
  </dialog>
<!-- timeout warning pop-up -->
```

CSS:

```
  border: none;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black background with opacity */
}
```

javascript

```
<script{%- if nonce %} nonce="{{ nonce }}" {% endif -%}>
  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
  document.body.classList.add("overlay");
  document.getElementById("popupDialog").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("closePopup").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.body.classList.remove("overlay");
    document.getElementById("popupDialog").style.display = 'none';
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have a _modal_, if you had, you wouldn't need to ask this question. Usually the main page is fully overlaid with a (semi)transparent element. That prevents mouse actions on the mainpage, but making the main page fully uninteractive is extremely hard, considering ongoing promises, timeouts and intervals, elements in the tabbing order accessible to via the keyboard etc.

Comment: Then I guess my question is how do I make my non-modal popup modal?

Comment: You can't, a modal window can be created only on the OS level. You can emulate some features, but JS is not capable to create a fully modal pop-up. (It [was possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) in old browsers, but that feature was removed for a while ago.)

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) is the closest you can get with `<dialog>` element.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bit complicating talking of modals, given lack of some common browser support. What is wanted here is something that acts like a modal, the whole page to be overlaid so that nothing underneath can be interacted with. The basis of that seems to be there in your CSS/JS with the overlay class on the body. But the CSS you give is incomplete, can you show us any relevant bits? What actually can you see when the pop up happens?

Comment: @AHaworth Maybe it's a bit complex, but given, that OP already uses that experimental element, and the support for its "modal" mode is practically as wide as the element itself (excluding only FF), I'd count it as a possibility. It also looks like they actually have that overlay, which blocks the mouseinteraction, and [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/ub9spfmd/), when the actual problem is a bit poorly described in the question. I can only assume, that this has actually something to do with the tabbing, and you can tab through the elements activating them and even inputs are writable.

Comment: Ah .. I wasn't paying enough attention to your code, when I sticked to the "modal" issue. The term "modal" is so widely misused, that it has almost become a synonym to "pop-up". You can't use `document.body` as an overlay, it's the bottom-most element on the page. Put a `div.overlay` just before your dialog, that makes your code to work as it was purposed to.

Comment: @Teemu, there's several widely used browsers that don't support 'proper' modals as yet so not a good idea to use them in production but I agree, 'modal' has come to mean popup - used all over the place as such including on SO and it would be better if it were separated out again especially with the increasing take up of implementations of 'real' modals as per your MDN link.

Comment: @AHaworth I wouldn't say ["widely used"](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share), but of course even only 1% of the markets is tens of millions of people.

Comment: Well, as I understand @Teemu the non-implementations include IE (relevant for older populations or the third sector still) and Safari, used all over the place, and Firefox (unless the user explicitly allows it). But maybe I've mistaken the warnings on MDN.

Comment: @AHaworth Probably you haven't misunderstood the warnings. Like I said, OP already uses `dialog` element (hence dropping all Safari and IE users), dropping the most of FF users (it's unlikely an intermediate web surfer would use about:config page) by using the modal mode doesn't make a big gap to the potential audience. The most important part of the statistics is the local market shares of the browsers, and at the end, the real target audience, it's really hard to give any advices relying on the global statistics.

Comment: @Teemu - agreed!

Answer (score 0):

I found an example on W3schools (I'm not proud) and modified it accordingly, so now my popup really is a modal.

HTML:

```
<!-- Timeout warning popup -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" tabindex="-1">
      <h1 class="heading-l" id="modal-title">{{t('sign-out-warning:heading')}}</h1>
      <p>{{t('sign-out-warning:paragraph')}}</p>
      <button class="g-button" id="closePopup">
        {{ t('sign-out-warning:continue') }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 40%;
}
```

javascript (the bit that makes it modal:

```
<script{%- if nonce %} nonce="{{ nonce }}" {% endif -%}>
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  modal.style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("closePopup").addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  );

</script>
```